# Displaying the meaning of an operator using Information

Tags: symbols, operators

I'm using CircleTimes ($\otimes$) operator defined as

```
a_\[CircleTimes]b_ := KroneckerProduct[a, b]
```

so I can use `a ESC c* ESC b` to write $a\otimes b$ instead of `KroneckerProduct[a, b]`. What should I do in order to find out the definition of the $\otimes$ symbol using `Information` function or assign a usage to this symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html):

> Mathematica follows the general convention that the function associated with a particular operator should have the same name as the special character that represents that operator.

Therefore the Symbol associated with the character `\[CircleTimes]` is simply `CircleTimes`.

```
a_\[CircleTimes]b_ := KroneckerProduct[a, b]

Definition[CircleTimes]
```

> ```
> a_\[CircleTimes]b_ := KroneckerProduct[a, b]
> ```

You can select the operator and press <kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up the documentation page, e.g. [CircleTimes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/CircleTimes.html).

Comment: Thanks. So I guess that it is better to define this operator as `CircleTimes[x_,y_] := KroneckerProduct[x,y];`

Comment: @Jarek No, your original definition is perfectly acceptable.  What did you infer that made you think otherwise?

Comment: I know that the first one work fine, but I think it is more consistent if I use the second, since I can add usage to `CircleTimes` but not to $\otimes$ (`CircleTimes::usage =""` is OK, but $\otimes$::usage not). Besides using $\otimes$ in a package is problematic.

Comment: @Jarek As you see fit.  Since I appreciate brevity I would use the operator form where it works, and the long form where it doesn't.  At least you now know what you're working with.